# vim tags navigation, change the sort order using VIM or CTAGS

Tags: c++, c, vim, ctags

I have a simple problem…

I have a **tags** file for c(c++) sources and I want to navigate through the **tags** using *vim*. My **tags** include sources and header, because I use the "header (.h)" for the documentation and the "sources (.c)" for the code.
My problem is that I want get the "sources (.c)" first and the "header (.h)" second. my *ctags* has it the other way around.

Question: is it possible to change the **sort** order for **tags** navigation in *ctags* or *vim* ??

Comment: You can try using `cscope` instead of `tags`. For `cscope`, it presents you with an interactive list, and you can then choose which file to visit. http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html

Comment: @jxh, While scope would be perfect for C, it has an extremely poor understanding of C++.

Comment: @Andreas, what do you mean by "first"? You mean when you hit `<C-]>` ?

Comment: Question: what are you using to create the tags file? Are you using ctags, Exuberant ctags, or Universal-ctags?

Comment: my ctags:

> ctags --version
Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Addresses: <dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net>, http://ctags.sourceforge.net
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex

Comment: with "first" I mean… if I do a tag search… using the ":tag .." or the "short-key" I want to get the the code FIRST and the header SECOND… by default

Answer (score 0):

Try using a numeric parameter, `vim(1)` tags support multiple tag definitions for each label, so you can use `2^]` to get the second tag definition, `3^]` to get the third, etc.